# What is the proper way to perform a SEARCH with logic AND using the APIs?

Tags: filter, rest-api, search-criteria

I'm having trouble performing a search using the APIs. Below is the request I'm performing to my Magento backend:

```
http://www.mybackend.com/rest/it/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=type_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=simple&searchCriteria[pageSize]=6&searchCriteria[current_page]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=color&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=41
```

What I want to get from this request is the first page (size of the page should be 6) of my SIMPLE products (not configurable) and they should have color 41 (which is green for me).

The result I receive is the following:

```
{"search_criteria":{"filter_groups":[{"filters":[{"field":"color","value":"41","condition_type":"eq"}]}],"page_size":6,"current_page":1},"total_count":2}
```

Along with all the green products, simple and configurable (that are not listed here for security). As you can see the filter I set to get only simple products, is overwritten by the second one, to get all the green products.

What is going wrong here? Can you help me?

Thank you!